# In which folder we need add database query in laravel4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am a beginner to laravel, have installed laravel4 and it works cool. Even I have done database configuration. If I want to fetch or insert or to do some database operation where I need to write database queries ? I wrote a simple code in router.php like below and am getting all values from the database. But I need to know where exactly do we need write this code snippet ? My am is to write a rest API. Please can some one help me out ?

```
 $users = DB::table('user')->get();
 return $users;
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends How you design your routing. if you route like this

```
Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', function () {

 }));
```

then you can do query in your routing page like

```
Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', function () {
   $users = DB::table('user')->get();
    return $users;
 }));
```

But if you call a controller in your routing like

```
Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@showHome'));
```

then you can do query in `showHome` method inside`HomeController` controller
like

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {
    public function showHome(){
          $users = DB::table('user')->get();
          return $users;
    }
}
```

**Note :** Controller directory is `app/controllers`

**Update**

If you would like to use `Model` then you need to create model in `App/models` folder like

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'user';
    public $timestamps = true; //if true then you need to keep two field in your table named `created_at` and `updated_at`
}
```

then query will be like this

```
$users = User::all();
return $users;
```

Comment: No need to use models folder ? I thought we need to write all database query in that folder.

Comment: No need to use model folder for fluent query.In model folder you just create model for every table. you can use model but not mandatory

Comment: Thank you so much.And If you can tell me how to send parameters to the query ? like if I want to send username and password in the rest API how can I check the existence of that username and password?

Comment: you can use where condition like `User::where('username', '=', 'testuser')->where('password', '=', 'testpass')->get();`

Comment: if you use model then read the documentation http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent

Comment: that is ok. But If I make it dynamic something like `public function userLogin($emailId,$password){
  $users = DB::table('user')->where('emailId',$emailId)->get();
        return $users;
  
 }` is not working

Comment: look this is not tutorial site. you must learn from documentation then when you face problem you can ask in stackoverflow